# Self join on dataset with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to carry out the equivalent of a self join or vlookup on my dataset. The problem is, I have duplicates in my dataset so this increases the size of my dataset by 5.

I cannot drop the duplicates because i need them in my dataset.

To give you context here is a sample of how my dataset looks

```
name  pts  opp  
 a     7    b
 c     6    b
 d     5    b
 a     7    c
 b     9    d
 d     5    c
```

The idea is return another pts column where I look at the pts associated with the opp. So the desired output would be

```
name  pts  opp  pts
 a     7    b    9
 c     6    b    9
 d     5    b    9
 a     7    c    6
 b     9    d    5
 d     5    c    6
```

Comment: what if `b` had 2 different values in `pts` column?

Comment: @anky_91 that's not possible in my dataset

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the `opp` column would not contain any duplicate values from `name` column, you can [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on `name` column and create a mapper series and using [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) , map it back:

```
df['pts2']=df['opp'].map(df.drop_duplicates('name').set_index('name')['pts'])
```

---

```
  name  pts opp  pts2
0    a    7   b     9
1    c    6   b     9
2    d    5   b     9
3    a    8   c     6
4    b    9   d     5
5    d    2   c     6
```